# the order of the execution inner the second argument of apply method

Tags: javascript

```
var arr1 = [0, 1, 2];
var arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
// Prepend all items from arr2 onto arr1
Array.prototype.unshift.apply(arr1, arr2) // arr1 is now [3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]
```

The above is a piece of javascript code.
I know the `array.prototype.unshift`.
I know the `apply` which demands the second argument must be a array or like-array.
But I can't understand why the result is `[3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]` but not the `[5, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2]`. Does that mean the arr1 first unshift `5`, second unshift `4`, finally unshift `3`? So it may be concluded that the apply's second argument is excuted from right to left?

can someone put it in details?:~)

Comment: The second argument of `apply` is the arguments array. So they would applied to `unshift`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `.apply` is the context (the `this`) and the second is an array of arguments.

So what you're actually doing is this:

```
[0,1,2].unshift(3,4,5);
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to how `unshift` works